# Is there any better way to get all the users Role name using Entrust at a time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am in need of User Role and permission management so I thought of giving Entrust package a try for saving time. While using it I needed to show all the users username and role name in route so I did this in a route

```
Route::get("user-with-role", function(){

$user = User::with('roles')->get();

foreach (User::with('roles')->get() as $u)
{
echo $u->username;

    foreach ($u->roles as $role) {

        echo " is ".$role->name;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

});
```

Is there any better way to get the role name instead of the inner foreach loop?

This is my DB structure for Users Table

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide DB Structure for USers table

Comment: `Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
   $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('email');
      $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
  }); `
this is the DB strusture

Comment: http://alexsears.com/article/using-entrust-to-add-roles-and-permissions-to-laravel-4

Comment: I just saw that post but it doesn't actually solves what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I can help more if you included your schema structure for users and roles if exists.  As well as your User model and Role model.  But here is the gist of what should be going on.  If you want a better answer...I need more from you.  Ideally you should be able to make an SQL join between users and roles or access the relationship with Eloquent ORM if you defined the relationships in your class.

You shouldn't be echoing HTML in your route function...that won't do you any good.  Also in your route function you should be returning something since that is a GET request and the server will be expecting a response...

**Route**

```
Route::get("users", function() {
    $users = User::select('username', 'role')->with('roles')->get();
    return View::make('SOME VIEW')->withUsers($users);
});
```

**Blade View**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**User relation to roles**

Now generate the Entrust migration

`$ php artisan entrust:migration`

It will generate the `<timestamp>_entrust_setup_tables.php migration`. You may now run it with the artisan migrate command:

`$ php artisan migrate`

After the migration, two new tables will be present: roles which contain the existent roles and it's permissions and assigned_roles which will represent the Many-to-Many relation between User and Role.

Here you should have your Many to Many Relationship did you do this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't define any relationship as the hasRole trait from the Entrust has already defined it I guess. Or should I define relationship by myself? Thanks for answering.

Comment: in your User class you did use `use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;` before class definition as well as `use HasRole;` in the class definition?

Comment: yes,
 `   <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

 // This is trait for using entrust
    use HasRole;

 /**
  * The database table used by the model.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $table = 'users';

 
 
 protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
    } `

Comment: I have added to the answer.  If you installed Entrust correctly with the database migrations, you should have access to the Many-to-many relationship with eloquent orm.  If you did this please let me know

Comment: I have installed Entrust correctly. But I haven't defined Many to Many Relationship between User and Role as the hasRole Trait is already doing that. Since so far I did nothing wrong, is there any way I can access the role name like `$user->roles->name`

Comment: You didn't answer me. Did you run the migrations?

Comment: `User::has('roles')->get();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69922/discussion-between-rony-banik-arko-and-rafael).